# I have 6 to 7 SSIS Packages which are in 2008 I have to Upgrade it to 2012/2014

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, msbi

Upgrade was Successful but SSIS package not picking up configuration files correctly.
I have Existing SSIS Package which Takes XML Configuration. I have Made Changes to it then It doesn't Shows Changes in dts.config rather it get's overridden by previous Data Connections in Project.

Dts Config file :-

Data Source=xyz.24.186.xy\amcdev;User ID=sa;Password=saadmin;Initial Catalog=WWDM_Production;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=xyz.24.186.xy\amcdev;User ID=sa;Password=saadmin;Initial Catalog=CCRS_CCS;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;
mailhub.utc.com

> 

When I Deploy it

dtsx File :-

OLEDB@[User::strDest]
0AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAADutPyNTdokihIguazsSJHgAAAAAIAAAARABUAFMAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAABJ6xoro9ACvhX+NbGT22PMAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAABRUhjp1vqWoK7hCFl9CLbsQAAAAbmINhUslz4W2w4q3frFuuBQAAACntC1ObkKH4fGzhageo3MOAIiMvg
Data Source=OTINWISRCDT020;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=WWDM_Prod;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;

[When I try To open Project in BI 2008 it Shows me Previous Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzuxT.png)

Comment: What changes did you make?

Comment: @TabAlleman - I have Added Description and Image For more Details, please help

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what is the problem you are trying to describe.

Comment: @TabAlleman  :- I have 6 to 7 Packages which are in 2008 I have to Upgrade it to 2012/2014 Upgrade was Successful but SSIS package not picking up configuration files correctly.

Comment: I would destroy and re-create the config files in the new environment.